# iOS Swift delegates

Tags: swift, delegates

I'm very new to Swift, and I'm having trouble using delegates. When the user taps on a table row in AdminAddCatTableViewController, I want to drop a pin on the map at the user's current location in AdminViewController, and I'm trying to do this using a delegate. Obviously there's something wrong with my code, as the pin does not get dropped.

In AdminAddCatTableViewController, I have

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol AddCatDelegate: class {
    func addPin(sender: AdminAddCatTableViewController)
}

class AdminAddCatTableViewController: UITableViewController {

weak var delegate:AddCatDelegate?

let admin = "secret-number"
let ref = Firebase(url: "firease_url")

@IBOutlet weak var snowballGPSLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var smokeyGPSLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shadowGPSLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var spotsGPSLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sunnyGPSLabel: UILabel!

var catRefArray: [AnyObject] = []

var coord:String = ""

let shareData = ShareData.sharedInstance

func updateCoord() {
    if let bar = self.shareData.someString {
        self.coord = bar
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "updateCoord", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var catNameArray: [AnyObject] = []

    catNameArray.append("Snowball")
    catNameArray.append("Smokey")
    catNameArray.append("Shadow")
    catNameArray.append("Spots")
    catNameArray.append("Sunny")


    for i in 0...4 {
        catRefArray.append(self.ref.childByAppendingPath("admin").childByAppendingPath(self.admin).childByAppendingPath(catNameArray[i] as! String))
    }

    catRefArray[0].observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let value:String = snapshot.value as? String {
            self.snowballGPSLabel.text = value
        }
    }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
// same for the other rows
    })
}  

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        let ref0 = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("admin").childByAppendingPath(self.admin)
        ref0.updateChildValues(["Snowball": self.coord])
        delegate?.addPin(self)
    }
// same for other rows
}
```

In AdminViewController, I have

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class AdminViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


@IBAction func logOutDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("adminToLogin", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var previousLocation : CLLocation!

var latitude = 0.0;
var longitude = 0.0;

//Declare Class Variable

let shareData = ShareData.sharedInstance


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //On loading the screen the map kit view is shown and the current location is found and is being updated.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .NotDetermined || status == .Denied || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()



    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode(rawValue: 2)!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //updates the location
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

    self.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
    self.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude

    self.shareData.someString = "\(self.latitude)" + "," + "\(self.longitude)"
    print(self.shareData.someString)
}
}

extension AdminViewController: AddCatDelegate {
func addPin(sender:AdminAddCatTableViewController) {
    // drop a pin
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    let coordinate = mapView.userLocation.coordinate
    let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    dropPin.coordinate = coordinate
    dropPin.title = "Cat"
    mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
}
}
```

Comment: If you are segueing from AdminViewController to AdminAddCatTableViewController, you have to set the delegate property of AdminAddCatTableViewController to self while segueing.. If you have defined the segue in storyboard, just implement the prepare for segue method,  get the destination controller and set the delegate property to self

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        

        if segue.identifier == "Identifier" {
            
            let dvc =  segue.destinationViewController as? AdminAddCatTableViewController
            dvc?.delegate = self
        }
    }

Comment: You don't set `delegate` so it is nil. `delegate?.addPin(self)` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are never setting the delegate on your AdminAddCatTableViewController, so it is always nil and never called.

Why do you even have an extension of AdminViewController? Just remove the extension and make AdminViewController implement the delegate. To set the delegate implement something like this in your AdminViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier" {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? AdminAddCatTableViewController {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```